# shifts the vertex normal angle after deleting vertices

Tags: normals

There is such a strange method of placing an object on the center of a certain face with the desired orientation of this object. The orientation is based on the vertex normal.

To complete the idea - need just to delete unnecessary vertices. But after deleting the vertices, the angle of the vertex normal changes slightly :( The orientation of the object is not centered, does not match to face normal

Is it possible to prevent the vertex normal angle change after deleting adjacent vertices?

[.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e8hoxgmc8yQn9zsalS8UOpRacBir5wFi/view?usp=share_link)

[image]

Maybe there is an easier way to implement such conditions:

- the object is placed on the desired face. Not on every face of the object
- the object is placed in the center of the face
- object orientation coincides with face normal

The method through the node geometry is even more complex, confusing: it is more suitable for advanced, not for beginners.

Thank you

Comment: At the moment, you are using instancing:  the 'Instance on Vertex' mechanism. If you want instances on face-centers.. why not 'Instance on Face' ? Please summarize the _result_ you want.  (eg: 'Instances on selected face-centers, aligned to face normals') if that's what you mean.

Comment: >>If you want instances on face-centers.. why not 'Instance on Face' 
This is not enough for the conditions described under the GIF.
Namely: the orientation of the object must match to normal of the face. If you use 'Instance on Face' - the object is directed primitively. Not the way I need it.

>>Please summarize the result you want.
Did you read the text under the gif? Please read. There are described the conditions or result
(conditions must be met together. Not one of)

Comment: >>eg: 'Instances on selected face-centers, aligned to face normals'
It looks like I wrote it. But described in three paragraphs (below the gif)
thank you

Comment: Hi @blenduser .. sorry.. I was being a bit dim. It's true, instancing on faces [doesn't give control over spin around normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/faces.html#limitations-considerations). Is [this](https://blend-exchange.com/b/xxrS2nVp/) the beginning of an acceptable solution? I know,, it's GN ... :(

Comment: Thank you.  I wrote under the gif that the way through the [geometry nodes](https://youtu.be/Fl-igAAMCeM), it is difficult for a beginner. But apparently this is the only way for this purpose.

Is there any official way to export a chain of nodes from one project to import that chain into another project?

Comment: [it looks](https://youtu.be/7s01gaMR9sc) like the answer to my question about node chain export

Comment: .. looks like it. I'll write that one up, if you want.